# My toolbar overlay my map

Tags: android, layout, fragment

I have next layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="sdfsf.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context="com.example.app.MapLocationActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

When I create my google map look like toolbar is over map and hide top area. But I want to display map on visible area. How to set fragment in my @layout/content_main?

Comment: can u post complete layout file

Comment: What is the `root layout` of your file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are using CoordinatorLayout so MapView will be displayed under AppbarLayout, you can wrap AppbarLayout and MapView into LinearLayout or just put:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

in your MapView:

```
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context="com.example.app.MapLocationActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Thank you!